# How to make systemd network-online.target wait for multiple networks?

Tags: debian, linux-networking, systemd

We have an ESXi virtual machine running Debian 10 and are encountering a problem with postfix starting too early. This is causing issues with resolv.conf not being populated before the postfix chroot. I've ensured that both

- /lib/systemd/system/postfix.service
- /lib/systemd/system/postfix@.service

files have the line

```
After=network-online.target nss-lookup.target
```

However we have multiple nics installed in this VM, with the /etc/network/interfaces file containing

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug ens192
iface ens192 inet static
        address 10.1.0.29/21
        dns-nameservers 10.1.0.20 10.1.0.23 

# The secondary network interface
allow-hotplug ens224
iface ens224 inet static
        address 192.168.1.8/24
        gateway 192.168.1.240
```

When I run

```
grep -E "(Postfix Mail Transport Agent|e1000|Link is Up|link is not ready|link becomes ready|resolv.conf differ|target)" /var/log/syslog
```

I see that network-online.target only waits for one of the nics to be online.

```
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    1.738897] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    1.738897] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    1.739922] e1000e 0000:0b:00.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    1.795419] e1000e 0000:0b:00.0 0000:0b:00.0 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    1.859484] e1000e 0000:0b:00.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1)
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    1.859486] e1000e 0000:0b:00.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    1.859558] e1000e 0000:0b:00.0 eth0: MAC: 3, PHY: 8, PBA No: 000000-000
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    1.860245] e1000e 0000:13:00.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    1.915403] e1000e 0000:13:00.0 0000:13:00.0 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    1.979239] e1000e 0000:13:00.0 eth1: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1)
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    1.979240] e1000e 0000:13:00.0 eth1: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    1.979290] e1000e 0000:13:00.0 eth1: MAC: 3, PHY: 8, PBA No: 000000-000
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    1.981312] e1000e 0000:0b:00.0 ens192: renamed from eth0
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    1.994070] e1000e 0000:13:00.0 ens224: renamed from eth1
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    4.577652] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ens224: link is not ready
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    4.583595] e1000e: ens224 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 systemd[1]: Reached target System Initialization.
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 systemd[1]: Reached target Sockets.
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 systemd[1]: Reached target Basic System.
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 systemd[1]: Reached target Timers.
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)...
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 systemd[1]: Reached target Login Prompts.
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    4.671007] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ens192: link is not ready
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    4.671206] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): ens224: link becomes ready
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    4.675749] e1000e: ens192 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
Jan 12 18:46:54 assp0 kernel: [    4.676553] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): ens192: link becomes ready
Jan 12 18:46:55 assp0 postfix/postfix-script[750]: warning: /var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf and /etc/resolv.conf differ
```

I thought there was something you could write in the network config to indicate that connection was required before the OS would consider the network to be up, but I can't seem to find that info.

Before I cludge together something that works enough for us, I would like to know how to make network-online.target wait for either all nics, or preferably, the ones I specify. **- Edit -** the cludge I spoke of was adding a delay to the boot sequence.

**Edit**: I found a link to what I was thinking of, but it is in CentOS and is the [IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88895/what-is-the-ipv4-failure-fatal-ifcfg-directive-and-under-what-scenarios-would-i) line added to one of the ifcfg files. Does Debian have something similar, and do you think that would affect the triggering of the systemd targets?

**Edit**: enabling the systemd networkd services looks like it could be helpful, when reading about [systemd-networkd-wait-online.service](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.8.en.html). Before I go converting to using the Network Manager (networkd) config setup, am I reading that correctly and it would solve this issue?

Comment: Which `resolv.conf` is not populated?  `/var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: @fpmurphy that is correct `/var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf` is missing the nameserver entries.

Comment: Can you switch away from the antiquated Debian network scripts and use networkd? The network is only supposed to be considered online when _all_ interfaces are up, but I suspect those old 1990s-era scripts are indicating online when _any_ interface is up.

Answer (score 1):

Systemd automatically assumes that the network is online as long as the target ( I guess it depends on eiter network.service or NetworkManager.service on RHEL) report that it started.
We got a problem with dnsmasq reporting that it started, but actually it needed just a little bit more time before serving NFS mounts . As a workaround you can:

1. Create a service that will be executed after your network service and before your postfix
2. Set a delay in your network service (maybe a PostExec stanza)
3. Create a "prestart delay" via "ExecStartPre=" entry in your postfix service

Here is an example of the network.service on CentOS7:

```
# /run/systemd/generator.late/network.service
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator
[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network
Description=LSB: Bring up/down networking
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=graphical.target
Before=network-online.target
Before=network.target
Before=vxpbx_exchanged.service
```

For 2) you can create something like this:

```
#cat /etc/systemd/system/network.service.d/01-delay.conf
[Service]
ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 5
```

For 3) you can create something like:

```
#cat /etc/systemd/system/postfix.service.d/01-delay.conf
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5
```

Of course, those are just workarounds and this needs to be addressed via a bug.